# Can an Israeli work in public on second-day yomtov if there are non-observant Jews around?

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, yom-tov, chutz-laaretz

Shulchan Aruch says an Israeli Jew who is just visiting non-Israel should not work in public on the second day of Yomtov so long as he is in "yishuv" (and commentaries explain "yishuv yisrael") -- a city inhabited by Jews.

I think there are places in the United States where you could draw a hundred-mile radius where you won't run into a single yomtov-observant Jew -- but you will run into Jews who don't observe. How about in those places?

Comment: Isn't the whole thing about breaking from the minhag hamakom? Do nonobservant Jews have a minhag?

Comment: Re "Do nonobservant Jews have a minhag?" - From a practical (non halachic) perspective, yes, they do. For example, many Reform Jews don't eat *kitniyot* on Pesach.

Comment: relevant: notes 7-9 on [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Second_Day_of_Yom_Tov#Halachot_of_an_Israeli_outside_of_Israel) and http://halachayomit.co.il/en/ReadHalacha.aspx?halachaid=603

Comment: I would not be so sure about your "no Jews" thing. I live in Midland, Texas, a city without even an Orthodox synagogue, yet I am a Yom Tov observant Jew. :) I would be willing to bet the same about other remote cities, because I have run into Jews in the most remote West Texas towns.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a Rosh Kollel that question. After checking he told me a Jew living in Israel cannot go to a place where there is an organized Jewish community (I assume based on [SA OC 496:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.496.3?lang=bi)). The fact that there are isolated Jews is not an issue (luckily since, unless you go to a real desert, there is always a risk of having isolated Jews). In my case, I was able to fly to an airport in *chu"l* on *yom tov sheni* since there was no organized community there.

**The same ruling would apply to your question and allow a Jew living in Israel to go the isolated places you describe.**

I have now seen that R David Sperling rules in the same way [here](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=6930)

> [...] there are major rabbinic opinions that allow it. This is because
>   when in transit you stay in the **airport which is considered similar
>   to a "desert"** *(ed: despite the fact there are nearly certainly
>   individual Jews in the airport)* – that is a place that does not yet
>   obligate you to refrain from labor on second day Yom Tov (see the work
>   Yom Tov Sheni BeHalacha, 3:11)
>
> [...]
>
> if you are already **in a city that has a Jewish community in it**
>   (and not just passing through the airport), it is forbidden to fly out
>   of it on second day, for it would be forbidden to drive to the airport

See also [MB 496:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.496.10?lang=bi)